# Ceiling fan motor disassembly

Tags: ceiling-fan, electric-motor

Took apart a ceiling fan. Want to take apart the motor, but this thing looks like it was assembled tight, like a freaking bearing. I want to get to the goodies inside. I've taken out every screw there was and pried and pried but the two halves of the casing won't come apart. Tips??

Comment: Pictures might help. Try twisting. Doublecheck for deliberately hidden screws. Then bring on the sledgehammer, or the hydraulic press if it was really pressed like a bearing.

Comment: The guts of motors are frequently held together by retaining rings on the rotor shaft; often near the bearing itself. Look for them and remove. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retaining_ring

Answer (score 1):

The motor itself is usually assembled on to the shaft and housing using pressed on bearings. You won't be able to separate them without destroying the motor. Since the motor is intended to never be serviced, there's no reason to allow for them to be disassembled; doing so would only add more parts to potentially fail or loosen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect to use it as a fan again but here's what I did: (trying to make a generator): get a dremmel tool and go around the top of the casing where you know there aren't could or anything and cut it off piece by piece. The bearings are welded to the case, and I had to chisel them apart. It's a slow process but it's better than just throwing it away. Actually you could carve around the bearings on either side and the case sides should just come off then.  Basically just make sure not to cut the wires